# How many characters are there in Full Metal Alchemist: Brotherhood?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

How many characters are there in *Full Metal Alchemist: Brotherhood*?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. To get a specific answer, what is considered a "character"? Any people with names? Or everyone who plays a role in the plot? Or only listed in the official character introduction and resources? Or...? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Relevant: https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Fullmetal_Alchemist_characters?so=search#OTHER_CHARACTERS , although it includes characters from the 2003 continuity (film included) without making a very clear distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the list of all characters from Full Metal Alchemist franchise [here](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Fullmetal_Alchemist_characters). They also highlighted the characters based on adaptation/movie/manga-only. Based on my rough counting, the series has around 200 characters.